# v8 hello world example link error

Tags: c++, linux, v8

> I read [V8 hello world](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started) example, and follow the steps in the document to build v8 successfully.
>
> But when I compile the example code, link error occured. Here comes my computer detail and error prompts.
>
> 1. OS Ubuntu 13.10 amd64
> 2. GCC (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
> 3. Compile command:

```
g++ -Iinclude hello_world.cc -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/native/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base.x64,snapshot},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt
```

> **Error prompts**
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: /home/leon/Documents/v8/v8/out/native/obj.target/v8_base.x64/src/platform/mutex.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggests that you need to add the `pthread` library to your link command. Just append `-lpthread`.

(It's a bit odd that it identifies exactly which library you need, then tells you it refuses to use it because you didn't list it on the command-line...)

Comment: For those confused by the linker error, `DSO` stands for dynamic shared object.